# ROS Answers SE migration: kinect urdf

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Where can I find and how can I add a urdf file of the kinect to urdf of my robot.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110151/kinect-urdf/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look into the turtlebot package. In the turtlebot_description folder you can find the kinect.urdf.xacro file, look here to get started [kinect.urdf.xacro](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/hydro/turtlebot_description/urdf/sensors/kinect.urdf.xacro). You can find the description of kinect inside with robot model for the turtlebot. You can ignore other parts as you only want the kinect description. Copy and paste the kinect description and use it for you new urdf file.  Start from the [urdf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) and [tf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials)on ros wiki.

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2013-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0